# sd card not detecting in beaglebone black

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card

Working on Linux, I built the yocto bitbake console image with the help of this link https://www.campana.vi.it/blog/debian-stretch-yocto-beaglebone-black/.

After building the console image, and getting the uImage, MLO and uEnv.txt files, those were copied into the SD-card and the card moved into the beaglebone black.

But here card is not detected and `ssh debian@192.168.7.2` to the server is not connecting.

How can I enable the usb 2.0 in already built images?

Comment: *"card is not detected"* -- Based on what?  Are you trying to boot from the SD card or mount it?   What are you using for a console?    *"`ssh debian@192.168.7.2` to the server is not connecting"* -- What  is the significance of this?  What *"server"* is at 192.168.7.2?

Comment: Thank you for the replay,I am trying to boot from the sd card..ssh debian@192.168.7.2 this is the beaglebone board  address ,and i put that sd card into the beaglebone board after that, connecting  board to the linux computer, that time it is not showing any files ,not detecting that board....

Comment: You are still vague.  What are you using as a console, and how do monitor the progress of booting?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "safely remove"? I'd guess not...

This is exactly the kind of problems you get by not un-mounting/ejecting/"safely remove" storage media.

Windows and most other OS's buffer a lot of data to get better read and write speed, the data isn't written to the media immediately as you "copy" files.

The write is only GUARANTEED to be finished as you eject the media, log out or shut down your computer.

Note 1: SLEEP MODE may be a problem.
Note 2: Wait until the device is clearly at rest, not active; I believe e.g. Windows (again!) tells that it is finished a few seconds before the process actually is done.

---

Assuming the instructions behind your link makes sense, I do not read Italian.
This is unlikely to be caused by any driver as the card doesn't mount.

**To attempt to solve the problem:**

1. Put the card back in the linux computer and see if shows up,
   allowing to check content (list and read files).
2. Use `lsblk` to see where it is mounted (find the /dev/sdxx -style
   device name), then
3. try to run `sudo fsck.fstype -p /dev/sdxx` for the fstype you have
   on the card.

Apart from that I believe you either missed some step or did not unmount the card correctly. If the above doesn't help you might need to redo the process (reformat the card) and pay attention to every detail.

Comment: Thank you for quick replay,I removed the sd card after ejecting only,when i am connecting the sd card with the help of card reader its showing those images..but when i am trying with the help of beaglebone board it is not even detecting,and i copied those images into the sd card with the help of some scripts files by follwing this site http://jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/beaglebone-systems-with-yocto.html..I am not getting , what is the problem..how can i solve ..

Comment: can I need to install any usb drivers for that built images,if yes then which driver and how to install that one?...

Comment: Thank you,as per suggested i format that sd card and again copied that binaries.  shutdown the system and started once again ,while connecting now its asking the password when i am entering the password giving error permission denied..can you help..

Comment: for your second suggestion ,even I am also not able to read the italian ,I translate that italian into the english, and I read,As I follwed, to attempt to solve the problem but third point ,when i am giving that command getting command not found...